# Extracting data points (statistics) from matplotlib and equations, no output from code and to_excel file return errors

Tags: python, excel, pandas, statistics

I am noob here so be Patient, I had the following code, that I wanted to extract the X,Y and Z into a list (so I can copy them later in excel, and play with the numbers), (I can plot them already into Graph, but I am going the other way around), I asked before here, and I got some tips, but the code runs without saving any files (also, I tried to save as (df.to_excel(xyz_path, index=False) but I am getting an error, when I use "to_csv), the code runs without error but there is no outcome. Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  
from matplotlib import cm  
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter  
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
N = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
M = np.arange(0, 15, 1)
N, M = np.meshgrid(N, M)
DNM = 3992.88*N - 2585.96*M

#
x, y, z = N.ravel(), M.ravel(), DNM.ravel()
#
limits = np.logical_and(z >= -25000, z <= 20000)
x, y, z = x[limits], y[limits], z[limits]
#
xyz = np.column_stack((x, y, z))
df = pd.DataFrame(xyz)
xyz_path = "xyz.csv"
df.to_csv(xyz_path, index=False)

#surf = ax.plot_surface(N, M, DNM, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet,
 #       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
#ax.set_zlim(-25000, 20000)

#ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
#ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

#fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=10)

#plt.show()
```

for the code to extract and save the X Y Z points, so I can play with the numbers and do some analysis on them. It would be nice if I can save them on an excel sheet directly.

Comment: Make sure you have the suitable write permissions to the `xyz_path`?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by that. you please clarify

Comment: sorry to bother, i found the saved csv file in a whole other directory. thank  you very much